# display dynamic cards with different heights using grid css without gutter

Tags: html, css, css-grid

How to create a dynamic grid system using css3.
I'd like to achieve an overview page with multiple cards with different heights and order of displaying cards should be the same.

Cards with different heights will be displayed on the dashboard based on the config settings so it should be auto-adjusted. 
Please help me to write generic css for it.

```
HTML:

<div class="wrapper">
  <div style="height:50px" id="foo-1">One</div>
  <div style="height:50px" id="foo-2">Two</div>
  <div style="height:50px" id="foo-3">Three</div>
  <div style="height:100px" id="foo-4">Four</div>
  <div style="height:50px" class="fifth" id="foo-5">Five</div>
</div>


CSS3:

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(550px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
  grid-gap: 10px;
 }
```

Please refer:
https://codepen.io/prashantbiradar92/pen/MWgXGpG?&editable=true

Problem:

The div with id foo-1,foo-3,foo-5 should be in 1 column and foo-2, foo-4 in 2nd column, with no whitespace. It should display in order.
So currently there is gutter for the div foo-5. So I have to adjust the div foo-5.

Comment: Should there always be only 2 columns in the grid? Now their number is changing

Comment: @hisbvdis Yes max 2 columns in the grid. And min 1 grid for lower resolution device.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @PrashantBiradar , Updated the answer. This is what you need?

Comment: @hisbvdis. Thank you. This is what I needed.

Comment: @PrashantBiradar, If my answer helped you, please mark it with a decision.

Comment: @Paulie_D Thanks, I have updated problem. I got an answer from hisbvdis.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need something like this?
https://codepen.io/hisbvdis/pen/XWrYqqO

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.wrapper {
  border: 2px solid #f76707;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff4e6;
}

.wrapper>div {
  border: 2px solid #ffa94d;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #ffd8a8;
  padding: 1em;
  color: #d9480f;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(550px, 1fr));
  grid-auto-rows: 50px;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.col-1 {
  grid-column-start: 1;
}

.big {
  grid-row: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="col-1" id="foo-1">One</div>
  <div id="foo-2">Two</div>
  <div class="col-1" id="foo-3">Three</div>
  <div class="big" id="foo-4">Four</div>
  <div class="col-1" id="foo-5">Five</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, @hisbvdis. It helped me in designing dynamic grid with different heights CSS.         I dont have a rep to upvote this answer.

Comment: @PrashantBiradar, Thank you, friend. But I meant make a mark here. Screenshot: https://prnt.sc/p5sxvy. But if you do not have enough reputation, it`s okay. Good luck and thanks for your comment.

Comment: Done. Thanks again. Need to learn much more about StackOverflow.